# Moving Laravel project from CentOs 6.8 to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-4

When moving laravel project from centos to ubuntu 16.04 all blade views failed to display only blank screen is displayed as result. I am using laravel 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries and error I found 2 options

Option 1:

```
Remove all comment in view
```

This fix the error for short time may be will save some

Option 2:

```
Find app/storage/views/
And remove any previously auto generated file.
```

This second option become great for me thanks.